# Bad access in ReachabilityCallback

Tags: ios, reachability

I am getting bad access in following code, what can be the reason?

```
static void ReachabilityCallback(SCNetworkReachabilityRef target, SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags, void *info) {
#pragma unused (target, flags)
NSCAssert(info != NULL, @"info was NULL in ReachabilityCallback");
NSCAssert([(__bridge NSObject *) info isKindOfClass:[Reachability class]], @"info was wrong class in ReachabilityCallback");
```